# Spring Security Test case Issue with @WithMockUser

Tags: java, spring, junit, spring-security, mockito

I have Service class as shown below with 1 method

This method will only be accessed if user has WRITE role but my test case with READ role is able to access but it **should not** be able to access. I don't know what's wrong I am doing here.

```
@Service
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class DownloadPhasesFilesService implements IDownloadPhasesFile {

    @Override
    @PreAuthorize(value = "hasAnyRole('ROLE_WRITE')")
    public String getPhase2FilePathRoleWise(final BatchJob batchJob) {
        log.info("DownloadPhase2Service::getPhase2FilePathRoleWise for batchjob id {}", batchJob.getId());
        return batchJob.getPhase2FilePath();
    }
}
```

Here is my Unit Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
public class DownloadPhasesFilesServiceTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private DownloadPhasesFilesService downloadPhasesFilesService;

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(authorities = {"ROLE_READ" })
    public void getPhase2FilePathRoleWise_asdfasdf_asdf() {
        //Given:
        final BatchJob batchJob = BatchJob.builder()
                .id(1L)
                .telSecJobId("123")
                .status(PHASE_TWO_COMPLETED)
                .phase2FilePath("phase2")
                .baseMac(new MacAddress("aa:bb:cc:dd:ee:ff").getPlainMacAddress())
                .tenant(Natco.builder().natcoCode("pl").build())
                .model(Model.builder().modelName("modelName").oemName("oemName").build())
                .build();

        final String phase2FilePathRoleWise = downloadPhasesFilesService.getPhase2FilePathRoleWise(batchJob);
        Assertions.assertEquals("phase2", phase2FilePathRoleWise);
    }
}
```

I have even used **@WithMockUser(authorities = {"ROLE_READ" })** with my Test, this does not help and test cases are passed but test case must **FAIL** here bec **READ** role is not equal to **WRITE** role.

Here is my dependency in gradle:

```
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
```

Can anyone guid me here ?

Comment: Your tests are not using anything from Spring, therefore they won't initialize the proxys and other infrastructure beans needed for method security. I'd recommend creating an integration test using for example `@SpringBootTest` in order to verify method security.

Comment: But I already have Integration test and which are running fine, I want to strictly do it for Unit Test Cases.

Answer (score 0):

You must run Test with Spring, use `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` or `@SpringBootTest` annotations on your top class test

Comment: I tried this but it does not work and getting following issue :  ```Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither GenericXmlContextLoader nor AnnotationConfigContextLoader was able to load an ApplicationContext from [MergedContextConfiguration@2c3f046c testClass = 
 at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:255)``` it is not able to load the application context ```java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext```

Comment: You are missing the definition of the context with the `@ContextConfiguration(classes = ...)` annotation in your test. As classes you might define single configuration(s) or your whole production application context (that includes all the others). The benefit of declaring just the configuration classes you need is that the whole bootstrapping for the test is faster.